# Retrieving OpenID data of a Steam account, returning null?

Tags: php, oauth, openid

I'm using Light-OpenID for PHP to authenticate and retrieve data.

For my OpenID provider URL I am using http://steamcommunity.com/openid/, as documented [here](http://steamcommunity.com/dev)-

> Steam OpenID Provider Steam can act as an OpenID provider. This allows
>   your application to authenticate a user's SteamID without requiring
>   them to enter their Steam username or password on your site (which
>   would be a violation of the API Terms of Use.) Just download an OpenID
>   library for your language and platform of choice and use
>   http://steamcommunity.com/openid as the provider. The returned Claimed
>   ID will contain the user's 64-bit SteamID. The Claimed ID format is:
>   http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/

I have specified my required array of data that I am requesting as such -

```
$openid->required = array(
                        'namePerson',
                        'namePerson/first',
                        'namePerson/last',
                        'namePerson/friendly',
                        'contact/email',
                        'email');
```

I have made sure my code works, have tested it with other providers such as Google and Yahoo.

I try to login using Steam, I am authenticated, yet when I want to retrieve data about the user using `$openid->getAttributes();` the array returns empty.

I have investigated more, and it appears Steam also serves data through its [Web API using GetPlayerSummaries](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API). I suppose I could use the 64BIT Steam ID from the authorization of the OpenID account to request the data, but this would require an API key, and parsing the data in PHP.

Is there a way to request this data using OpenID? Or do I have to manually parse everything through Steam's API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Steam can act as an OpenID provider. This allows your application to authenticate a user's SteamID without requiring them to enter their Steam username or password on your site (which would be a violation of the API Terms of Use.)

This answers a part of your question?
They use openId only for authentication - nothing more. In answer on other part i should say - yes you should obtain service key from steam and use GetPlayerSummaries method to get what you want. The parsing will be not problem because they support much formats for return (i would use JSON).